# rebar clean does not delete artifacts in sub_dirs

Tags: erlang, rebar

I'm using rebar 2.6.1 (rebar 2.6.1 R15B03 20150928_141254 git 2.6.1). I have a library directory as:

```
libs
  -- lib1
  -- lib2
  rebar.config
```

The rebar config in the libs directory is simply:

```
{sub_dirs, [
    "lib1",
    "lib2"
]}.
```

I realize that after compilation using `rebar clean` does not actually clean the ebin directories in lib1 and lib2. Could not find any doc on bash wiki. Any reason why the ebin are not cleaned?

Comment: **May be** it just don't. However you can try to implement https://github.com/rebar/rebar/blob/master/src/rebar_erlc_compiler.erl#L104

Comment: Or you can check with `rebar3`

Answer (score 0):

Rebar operates according to the 'context' of the directory it is processing, it decides if the directory is an app directory, or a rel directory, and if it isn't either it won't play, or at least it depletes its possible operations.

This is probably quite sensible to avoid accidents, because rebar is very modular in design, both in terms of how it provides core functionality, what it allows you to do in terms of extensions by way of rebar environment configuration, and provision of plugin modules for a particular build case.

My guess is that your sub directory is not perceived as being appropriate to be cleaned, perhaps because there is no app file or app.src file present in a sensible location that it can find. My rebar WILL clean sub directories IF I have a "./subdir/ebin/*.app" or "./subdir/src/*.app.src" for example, but if both of those are removed, it won't...

I'm not suggesting this as a solution, but similarly, if your sub directory looks like a rel directory, then maybe it will clean it for you then - I've not checked that - but you can try it yourself by adding a "reltool.config" file there.